# Height of tab (JTabbedPane) does not change

Tags: layout, tabs, size, height, jtabbedpane

As the title says, the height of my tabs is not increasing as it should, my code looks like this:

```
    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    JLabel iconInTab = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("myImage.png"));
    iconInTab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,80)); // is the size of my Image, I've also try to do this using getSize
    jtp.addTab(null,new JPanel());
    jtp.setTabComponentAt(0,iconInTab);
```

I've also try this using html but it did not work either:

```
    jtp.addTab("<html><p><p><p></html>",new ImageIcon("myImage.png"),new JPanel());
```

with the first code the problem is not the change of the size horizontally (the width change correctly), the problem is only on the height, with the second code, if I add multiple lines inside the html code, the text appear incomplete (just show the middle line) (also the width behaves as expected, the problem is the height). . .

why is this happening? or how could I get this done?

**Note:** S.O.: Mac OS X 10.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!! The problem was that the default UI over MAC OS X (com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneContrastUI), you only need to change it to the basicTabbedPaneUI (or the one of your preference), in my particular case I need to extend this class (it was a pain in the ***, because what I wanted was really complex)  to get the look & feel that I was expecting, if you have the same trouble just do this before adding your tabs:

```
     myTabbedPane.setUI(new BasicTabbedPaneUI());
```

**Note:** Checking the default UI of your TabbedPane, may solve many different problems.